# Prove that this sequence diverges to infinity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 +\frac{1}{n}\tag{displayed})^{n^2} = \infty$

I don't know how to tackle this one. Knowing that it diverges to infinity and thus does not have an upper bound, should I try to prove that it's an unbounded subsequence, if so how? Is that sufficient to show that $\infty$ is the limit?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Converges to infinity" is quite the oxymoron.

Comment: English is not my first language and I actually couldn't think of a n appropriate way to put it. What's the right way?

Comment: You could say *diverges to infinity*. For that matter, you could say *converges to infinity in the extended reals*. Or you could be very informal and just say that it *blows up*.

Comment: "Diverges."  Sorry for the sarcasm.

Comment: Thanks. No problem, didn't even catch it before you mentioned it.

Comment: Dear @RonGordon, what is wrong with "Converges to infinity"? It is more precise than "diverges"; not all divergent sequences converge to infinity!

Comment: @BrunoJoyal, I'm trying to understand that. So, divergent simply means that limit does not extend, but converging to infinity means that it does converge in extended real systems. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: 
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}\geq 1+n^2(\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see Bernoulli coming. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = + \infty$$

A sequence diverges to $+ \infty$, if $\forall k \in \mathbb{R}$,  $\exists N_k \gt 0$ such that $a_n \gt k$, $\forall n > N_k$.

Take any $k \in R$

Using (from above) 
$$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}\geq 1+n^2(\frac{1}{n})$$

$$= 1 + n^2/n$$

$$=1 + n > n > k$$

$$\iff n > k$$

Take $N_k = k$ are you are done.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Show that 

$\forall k \in R$ $\exists N_k > 0$ such that $n > k$ $\forall n > N_k$

Take any $k \in R$

Then if $N_k = n$ you are done.

Comment: Great, can you then show how it is done for this particular problem?

Comment: Not 100% certain of correctness, but that's how I'd approach it.

Answer (score -1):

An approach would be using the fact that:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e
$$

Comment: How would this approach work ?

Comment: Yes, I know about that. Sorry, if it wasn't obvious.

Comment: His limit would be equal with lim e^n, as n->infinity

Comment: @user2896626  this lacks rigour.

Comment: Why? Can you explain, please?

Comment: @user2896626 You seem to be assuming the following statement:  if $b_n$ converges to B, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} B^n$. While it may seem intuitive, this does not suffice to infer that it is true. We need a proof that it is true (In case it's realy true)

Comment: @user2896626 As a counterexample to the fact that you seem to assume: Set $b_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$. Then $b_n$ converges to $1$. However: $e=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n^n\not=\lim_{n\rightarrow} B^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow} 1^n =1$

Comment: I suggest you have a look at "real analysis". I liked it a lot when I first learnt it, I also expect that you will like it.

Comment: I wish someone directed me to read analysis when I was wasting my time in calculus

Comment: No. I don't agree with the step where you take n out. Let me remind you that I gave you a counterexample in one of my previous comments.

Comment: @Amr, your counterexample is wrong, because lim 1^n = 1^infinity which is not equal to 1 (it's an indetermination).

Comment: @Amr, also, I hope you agree that lim(a * b) = lim a * lim b. Using induction, for lim(a^n) we get (lim a)^n. With n->infinity, we can take it's limit to compute it, so it becomes lim( (lim a)^n)

Comment: @user2896626 $\lim_{n\rightarrow} 1^n$ is just the limit of the sequence that consists of $\{1,1^2,1^3,...\}$ which is just a constant sequence. A constant sequence has converges to the constant value. you might not have a proof for it, but you can feel it

Comment: @Amr, I don't agree. Look in this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms

Comment: Firstly, Do you still want to assert that for every sequence $b_n$ that converges to $B$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} B^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, I do, as far as the lim B^n exists.

Comment: But you don't agree that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1^n$ exists ?

Comment: No. As the wikipedia post mentions, it is a indetermination, like 0^0.

Comment: OK. Ask on math exchange here the following question: What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1^n$ ? and I expect with a very high degree that you will get answers telling you that its one and its value is one.

Comment: But that's not a good argument, but just a thing that I said to make you trust me. I did not argue about intermediates because I dont know their definition (I also doubt that you know their definition). However, I know the defintion of a limit , I know what it exactly is. Thus, I can argue with you about limits. In particular I can argue with you about the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1^n$.

Comment: @user2896626 The fact that $1^n$ results in an indeterminate form does not mean that its limit does not exist. In fact, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1^n = 1$.

Comment: Finally, I advice you to study analysis. I think you will like it. Your arguments are similar to the ones I made when I was studying calculus. In case you don't trust me (which is totally OK, as you don't know me) you may have the opinion of other people here on the site. Just ask a question and look at the  answers and their votes

Comment: While I agree with @Amr 's obejction that, in general, if $b_n\rightarrow B$, this does not guarantee that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n^n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} B^n$, in this particular case, it can be made to work.  Namely, since $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\rightarrow e$, for large enough $n$, $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n > 2$.  Then, for large enough $n$, $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2} = [(1+\frac{1}{n})^n]^n > 2^n$, so diverges.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Sure.